# What is the difference between “unacademic” and “nonacademic”?

Tags: meaning, difference, prefixes

Both the words mean "not academic," but is there any difference between *unacademic*, and *nonacademic*?
Is there any phrase where one of the words should be used instead of the other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Non-academic* is a simple neutral statement of allegiance. Non-academic experience is one you gain outside of school. Non-academic license for software is different than "software for educational use only".

*Unacademic* is inappropriate for academic standards. A paper that calls upon results of Tarot readings as source of prediction of construction durability is unacademic. The theory of Intelligent Design is unacademic.

Answer (score 0):

Both *un-* and *non-* are prefixes to the word *academic* to change the meaning.

According to Oxford English Dictionary (OED):

> non-, prefix
>
> Used to express negation.
>
> Prefixed to nouns of action, condition, or quality with the sense ‘absence or lack of’, often corresponding semantically to ‘not doing, failure to do’ (where a verb is implied by the noun, as in non-accomplishment, lack of accomplishment, failure to accomplish) or to ‘not being, failure to be’ (where an adjective is implied by the noun, as in non-activity, lack of activity, failure to be active).

And:

> un-, prefix1
>
> Expressing negation.
>
> In Old English the number of recorded forms in un- is very large, the prefix being freely applied with a purely negative force to several parts of speech, which may be classified as follows:  (a) simple adjectives, (b) simple adverbs, (c) past participles of strong and weak verbs, (e) simple nouns.

As far as I'm concerned, there is no distinction of meaning between non-academic and un-academic.

Comment: There is a distinction, e.g. Nikolai Yezhov is an [*unperson*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Newspeak_words#Unperson), but a dog would be a *nonperson*.